# No tests found for given includes after upgrade to Gradle 5.1.1

Tags: gradle, testng

We used to have a few commands like following:

```
gradlew test --tests *MyTest
```

For example the class MyTest is in the package `com.test.MyTest`.
When using a Gradle version < 5.0 this worked just fine but after the upgrade to 5.1.1 I get following error:

> No tests found for given includes: [*MyTest](--tests filter)

We have already replaced all such occurrences because I think using the full path to a class is much better. But I am wondering why this isn't working anymore.

BTW: I am using TestNG and the mentioned class has at least one public method annotated with `@Test`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the problem. It has nothing to do with the gradle upgrade or with TestNG.

Basically someone initialized a global variable in some other class and used an fixed index there i.e.

```
public class myClass extends Something{
    private final String name = names.getNames(0);
    ...
```

When we called the gradle task with * it executed that piece of code and in that case it lead to an **IndexOutOfBoundsException** because the list is empty at that point of time.

Executing following command helped me finding the problem:

```
gradlew test --tests *MyTest --debug
```

Answer (score 16):

It took me a lot of digging around to find the solution, so sharing it here. I solved the `No tests found for given includes: [*MyTest](--tests filter)` error by changing the Intellij settings according to https://linked2ev.github.io/devsub/2019/09/30/Intellij-junit4-gradle-issue/

Steps:

1. File > Setting (Ctrl+Alt+S)
2. Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > gradle
3. Run Tests using: Intellij IDEA

Comment: Thank You. Tried all other answers and finally you came to rescue

Comment: Nice one, also worked for Kotlin/Gradle setup for appium